# How to call a REST web service for Windows 8.1 phone app development

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I am new to Windows phone app development. I have installed free version of Visual Studio Express 2013 for windows.

I am trying to build a windows phone app for windows phone 8.1. 
My problem is on button click I want to call a REST back end web service which will return a response JSON Object.

I have looked over the forum but could not find anything which I could Successfully implement.

Can someone please point me to the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you start you need to add the following Nuget packages to your project:

- Json.NET (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)
- Microsoft HTTP Client Libraries (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/2.2.28)

If your json looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "title": "Hello"
  }
]
```

You need to edit the class of your object to "set a link" between the json properties and your object properties:

```
public class YourObject
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public String Id{ get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("title")]
        public String Title { get; set; }
    }
```

Explanation about the method below:
U make a new HttpClient() object that u use to make a "GET" to a given url. If the HttpResponse is success (that means data is available), you can do something with the data. In your case its deserialize the json data to an object.

```
public async Task<YourObject> GetObject()
        {
            YourObject o = new YourObject();

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
                {
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        o= await JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<YourObject>(content);
                    }
                }
            }
            return o;
        }
```

I hope my explanation is clear enough and that this helps u further.

Comment: tell me reason to build instance for starting return o; will return your new instance or from DeserializeObjectAsync. it is not clear. 
i suppose that you do not need build instance for o for starting. anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of good articles online which have almost the same title as the title of your question.  Still, here's a few steps

1. To make REST calls, you'll want to use a HttpClient class
2. The response data can be easily pulled out as a JSON string, which you will have to deserialize to your C# object. The best and most popular library to use to work with JSON is JSON.NET.

One of the top search results:
[Consuming REST Services in your Windows Store and Phone Applications](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2014/01/09/consuming-rest-services-in-your-windows-store-and-phone-applications.aspx)