# How call a service from Windows Phone 8.1 and be sync

Tags: rest, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to call a REST Service from a windows phone 8.1, the option to add a service reference no longer exists.

Thanks.

Comment: You have to use **HttpWebRequest** method for calling REST Services.Follow this  Link for further information: 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25682877/how-to-call-a-rest-web-service-for-windows-8-1-phone-app-development

Comment: I try with this but... is async! i need response sync. thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, you don't have an option to add service reference in Project targeting Windows Phone 8.1.

Comment: Thank's all for your help.